# Are anodized fan filters efficient at blocking EMI?

Tags: emc, fan, emi-filtering

I was looking for metallic fan grills to close a large fan aperture for EMC and found many had a non-conductive finish, e.g. [this one](https://docs.rs-online.com/877b/0900766b8158546e.pdf) claims to have an anodized finish.

[image]

Doesn't that make them completely inefficient at actually blocking radiated EMI? Or is the coating thin enough to establish good capacitive RF bonding to the chassis when pressed together?

### Experiments

Also, here is [short tutorial from Todd Hubing (LearnEMC)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_Zq6qiuuINE) that shows that metallic parts that aren't grounded still block *high* frequency magnetic radiation. Eddy currents form in the material negating the radiation. However, for intermediate frequency electric fields that have wavelengths longer than the floating piece and are still relevant for EMC, I believe the part would just float on the wave and re-radiate it to the other side.

Here is yet another [similar short Youtube experiment](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Sxqa7N-fuHM&list=PLT84nve2j1g9_TabWCWUy1LrVnHN_EHvT&index=22), that investigates electric field screening. The fellow proves that an ungrounded metal plate does absolutely nothing to screen electric fields. Admittedly, the frequency is low compared to the size of the objects. It could be that higher frequencies would be blocked/reflected.

*So to summarize*, these experiments prove that an ungrounded mesh will block high frequency magnetic fields and will not block low frequency electric fields.

### Question

The question is essentially: what about high frequency electric fields? As far as I recall, at high frequency there are only EM waves (one field component can't exist without the other), although that could be an invalid simplification. Therefore, blocking the magnetic components could be enough, which would be in line with @Bimpelrekkie 's claims in the comments but sort of opposite to what the rest of the world says :)

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie yes I believe that the mesh is all internally connected but won't connect to the chassis (only capacitively). But then, won't it simply float on the RF wave ??

Comment: Is your EMI radiated or conducted?

Comment: @winny I am talking about radiated EMI that might radiate through the large circular fan aperture in the chassis (~57 mm diameter).

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie I am trying to parse your statement into my patchy emi knowledge... then why is it always emphasized that all metal must be grounded to not become an antenna ? why is is metal-metal contact of chassis parts deemed such a must for EMC ? Eddy current will form in this mesh regardless of grounding ok.. but what about wavelength of ~100 mm.. no such eddy currents can flow in the grill. It would just float on the wave. or please explain why it doesn't or why that doesn't matter.

Comment: For what it's worth, that looks more like powder coating  or paint than anodized.

Comment: @Aaron  The RS page says it is an anodized black finish. But regardless: Basically the question is would an anodized part efficiently block radiated EMI through the fan aperture ? Or would a painted part work if the paint was intact and there was no electrical connection to the chassis ?

Comment: In general, you want to remove the anodized finish (or don't apply it) where a good metal to metal bond is required.  When an aluminum chassis is anodized, the parts of the chassis where metal to metal contact is needed, such as when bolting two parts of the chassis together or where an EMI gasket is going to be used, that part of the chassis is not anodized.

Comment: Whether the metal part/screen is anodized or painted, does not affect it's shielding effectiveness provided good metal to metal is made between the screen and the rest of the chassis.

Comment: @SteveSh same question as to Dirk below: "Does it mean conversely, that if the grill is not grounded to the chassis, it will be indeed entirely inefficient at blocking radiated EMI ?" Or would it be somewhat efficient ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question in the title is quite different from the one in your "Question" section. The former question is an engineering one, the latter is a pure physics concept which I'll address here. Regarding that, note that there's just one EM field/EM radiation. The "electric" and "magnetic" concepts are just two different views of the same thing. There are no separate "electric photons" and "magnetic photons".

The "electric" part is the non-uniform presence of charges, the "magnetic" part is their motion. Fields that don't vary in time can have a zero electric or magnetic component:

- A purely magnetic field means that charges are distributed exactly uniformly but they're all constantly circulating. (Yes, that's a very simplified semi-classical view, but it works for this purpose.)
- A purely electric field has no charge motion/circulation but a constant non-uniform spatial distribution of charge.

Once you go from a static field to one that does vary in time, there's no way to get rid of either component, because there will always be both spatial non-uniformity as well as charge motion (that is implied by the "time-dependent" part).

There's thus no way to selectively block one component without also affecting the other one, and this applies to any field with nonzero frequency, no matter how high or low.

Returning to the engineering part of your question and your observations, we can see that if the mesh isn't properly bonded all around:

- low frequencies get absorbed and re-radiated by the mesh acting as an antenna (this doesn't work for high frequencies due to eddy losses in the mesh),
- high frequencies have a short enough wavelength that they can just leak through the narrow gap between the mesh and the chassis (there will always be a gap, even if only some micrometers wide).

Eliminating the gap (ensuring good electrical connection) addresses both issues, because it makes the low-frequency antenna less and less efficient (more and more like a Faraday cage) and also closes the high-frequency leak path.

Comment: Thanks for the comprehensive assessment. So if I interpret you correctly: basically for "usual" radiated EMI frequencies up to ~6 GHz with a wavelength of 50 mm: This would be blocked fairly well, because the wavelength is too long to leak appreciably through the tiny gaps and cannot penetrate the material itself due to Eddy losses, *even if the mesh isn't grounded*. Correct ?

Comment: @tobalt Depends on your definition of "fairly well" (how much attenuation you actually need). I personally wouldn't say it's sufficient for most purposes. For lower frequencies, the re-radiation mechanism will still be plenty efficient if the mesh isn't grounded. Remember that in the LearnEMC video, the trace on the scope got just like 4x smaller, and that's in linear (amplitude) terms. In other words, just a few dB of attenuation. For real EMI shielding you typically need tens of dB of attenuation (99.9999…% absorption in linear terms) for it to make any sense.

Comment: @tobalt Perhaps an example to illustrate the efficiency of re-radiation, imagine a typical Yagi antenna. The directors there will happily re-radiate whatever minuscule power they receive, without losing most of it to eddies, and that still works perfectly well at many of hundreds of MHz. (Granted, those elements are optimized for that purpose, but it hopefully shows that eddy losses don't just magically swallow everything unless we're talking about microwaves).

Comment: I see it starts to make quantitative sense now.. That demo was at 10 kHz though. So naively, the attenuation at 1 GHz due to eddy losses would be already 100,000 times stronger.

Comment: @tobalt Indeed, that's why it works at gigahertz frequencies. Doesn't help you in the slightest if whatever you're trying to shield also radiates 100 kHz from a SMPS or a few MHz from some digital logic.

Answer (score 5):

There needs to be continuous contact between the screen, the frame, and the enclosure this thing is mounted on, along the entire circumference of the opening. Outside of this conductive circumferential path, surface coatings are of no consequence.

As shown, it looks like the frame-to-enclosure contact is in four corners through the screws. The screws are likely to locally scrape enough anodizing off that a not-entirely-dependable connection is formed. Of course this is makes the four segments of the frame half-wave dipoles.

The screen-to-frame contact seems entirely uncontrolled and I would expect that the screen acts just like an isolated conductive plate of a similar size would when placed in directly front of the opening.

In other words: the part you are showing **has not been designed for EMI suppression** - it's merely a mechanical/cosmetic part.

EMI filter screens are easy to tell: **shiny :)**. They are - the whole thing - bare metal with perhaps a conductive galvanic coating. Common materials are stainless steel and copper, and the pricing reflects that. That's what you should look for. It's a case of quality and performance not being free, I'm afraid.

Comment: I agree that regardless of its coating, this particular depicted mesh wouldn't make a good bond to the chassis. But anyway: As ungrounded conductive objects do undoubtedly block high frequency magnetic fields, how could the EM wave reach beyond the mesh (even if the mesh is not bonded to the chassis) ?

Comment: @tobalt If the mesh isn't properly bonded all around, it will act as an antenna for lower frequencies which absorbs the wave from the inside and then re-radiates it out. That won't happen for very high frequencies (due to high eddy losses in the mesh), but those waves are short enough that they can just leak around through the narrow gap between the mesh and the chassis.

Comment: @TooTea As i stated that part is an example. Imagine a really flat *anodized* part that leaves no gap with the chassis but is not electrically connected to it. Would it block EMI ?

Comment: @tobalt There's no absolute yes/no answer to that, it all depends on the frequency. Not being electrically connected implies that there is a gap (if only as thick as the layer of aluminium oxide or paint on the parts). The narrower that gap, the higher the frequency needs to be to leak through that gap.

Comment: @TooTea understood. Thank you. I believe your comment is what best answers the main question. If you want you could flesh it out a little and post as an answer.

Answer (score 4):

The anodized finish should not matter *provided* that the metal is grounded. This can be something of a problem through anodizing but I assume the screw to the case cuts through the oxide layer.

Comment: Does it mean conversely, that if the grill is not grounded to the chassis, it will be indeed entirely inefficient at blocking radiated EMI ?

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie But it can re-radiate

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie, whether or not an ungrounded shield blocks EMI depends largely on the frequency and skin depth at that frequency. At low frequencies, skin depth may be significantly larger than thickness of shield.

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie - and EMI fields can refract around the metal.  That's why, to be effective, an EMI enclosure, or chassis, needs to be continuous, with no unintended openings.

Comment: @Dirk Bruere - Or maybe the anodizing is removed where the screw mounts are.  In general you don't want to count on a screw/bolt cutting through the anodizing to ensure your shielding effectiveness.

Answer (score 4):

[Henry Ott](http://www.hottconsultants.com/) and the [Grounds for Grounding](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0471660086) folks would say it should be electrically connected to prevent EMI leakage from around the seams.
Also, the hole can be considered a slot, which can make the chassis a magnetic antenna (aka [slot antenna](https://electronicsdesk.com/slot-antenna.html)). Making the grill electrically connected to the chassis prevents the slot antenna formation.  A floating wire mesh will not stop low frequency magnetic radiation from a slot antenna.
[image]

Image from [Electronics Desk](https://electronicsdesk.com/slot-antenna.html)

Comment: Thanks @Aaron I have just added the last paragraph to my question, which proves that even floating metal *does* block high frequency magnetic radiation. But for an electric field, I can't see how a floating piece of metal would make a difference..

Comment: @tobalt Thanks, I just learned something new.  I updated my answer. The wire mesh will not block **low frequency** magnetic radiation.  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EZLu8v3tTfY

Comment: @tobalt Usually for EMI, one must block both low f and high f at the same time.

Answer (score 3):

Bottom line is this.  The anodizing or paint doesn't affect the shielding effectiveness of the screen, provided there is a good, low impedance (less than a couple of milliohms) bond between the screen and the chassis/box it's being mounted to.

Oh, and that there are no gaps around the edge of the screen and the chassis.

This assumes you need shielding effectiveness across a large part of the RF spectrum, MHz to GHz.  The lower your frequencies of concern, the more forgiving in so far as gaps and other openings go.

Answer (score 1):

The effect of grounding really depends on the frequency range you are trying to suppress.

At low frequencies (wavelength >> size of the shield) the shield can reduce the E field strength via capacitive coupling. Indeed, if the shield is not electrically connected to the rest of the circuit, it will not work: the E field inside the shield will attract charge carriers in the shield, and the opposite charge will build up on the outside, creating an external E field that escapes your shield. If the shield is grounded, the excess charge carriers will move to ground, and the E field outside the shield will be effectively zero.

At high frequencies (wavelength << size of the shield) the shield reduces the EM waves by allowing the Eddy currents to flow inside of it. If the shield is a perfect conductor, the EM wave is reflected inside the the shielded area. If the shield has resistance, the reflection is not perfect and some of the EM energy is absorbed by the shield. Grounding the shield has no effect because the currents will not leave the shield anyway. What will matter is the thickness of the shield compared to the [skin depth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skin_effect) of a given material at a given frequency.

In both cases, the fact that the shield has non-conductive coating has no impact on efficiency. Grounding wires are usually attached using toothed washers which are designed to make good contact, and paint should be scraped off around the grounding point. Everywhere else the shield will be likely surrounded by non-conductive materials such as air anyway.

Comment: Thanks, while CISPR up to 6 GHz is probably relevant, I am most concerned about kHz range stuff radiating into the device. Therefore, relying on eddy current absorption sounds like a bad idea and grounding seems mandatory.

Comment: @tobalt yes, in kHz range, grounding is mandatory for effective shielding, unless the shield is multiples of the skin depth. The skin depth of aluminum at 1 kHz is about 2.6 mm. An ungrounded aluminum sheet 2.6 mm thick would attenuate some. (Memory suggests something like 37%, but don't quote me on that.) A slab of aluminum 10 times that thickness, or about an inch thick would block 1 kHz noise effectively.

Comment: @DmitryGrigoryev. No, the spaces within the shield need to be shorter than the wavelength. So, six aluminum slabs in the form of a cube could form an ungrounded Faraday cage as long as the cracks between the slabs are small enough. But the dimension of the Faraday cage does not need to be on the order of a wavelength.